# Flask-MongoKit find_one()

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongokit

I'm trying to use Flask-MongoKit as follows (with both attempts to find_one failing):

```
app = Flask('app-name')

db = MongoKit(app)

db.register([database.Users])

with app.app_context():
    print db['users'].find_one()
    print db.Users.find_one()
```

When I used plain MongoKit (non-Flask version), and this worked (as follows)

```
db = Connection()

db.register([database.Users])
print db.Users.find_one()
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

The database and collection are defined as follows.

```
class Users(Document):
    __collection__ = 'users'
    __database__ = 'database'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? Are you getting an error? Can you share the traceback?

Comment: It returns none for the first example, and an actual result for the second example.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database? Where does `database` come from? Is that a module you're importing somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it's defined in the class. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Flask-MongoKit doesn't use MongoKit's `__database__` value. Instead, it uses an application config setting named `MONGODB_DATABASE`. If that isn't set, it defaults to a database named `flask`. If you change your code to

```
app = Flask('app-name')
app.config['MONGODB_DATABASE'] = 'database'
db = MongoKit(app)
```

your calls to `find_one()` should work.

The relative bits can be found [here](https://github.com/jarus/flask-mongokit/blob/95add18b382898eb82c7ff3dd0aa0fd6db0f5cb9/flask_mongokit.py#L118) and [here](https://github.com/jarus/flask-mongokit/blob/95add18b382898eb82c7ff3dd0aa0fd6db0f5cb9/flask_mongokit.py#L203-L208).